# sortedArrayUsingComparator int

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have an array of a dictionary that it sortedArrayUsingComparator sorts them based on the key;

```
listPerc = [listItem sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id a, id b) {
    NSString *first = [a objectForKey:@"perc"];
    NSString *second = [b objectForKey:@"perc"];
    return [first compare:second];
```

the problem is that this key is a numbers, and order is so for example: 1,10, 15, 17, 2, 23, etc. 
it does not calculate the magnitude of the number. 
how can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make them into NSNumber objects and compare those instead. Either store them as NSNumbers to start with (preferred method) or convert them when comparing (slower).

Converting an NSString to an NSNumber can be done with:

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:string];
[f release];
```

Answer (score 19):

Can't you return the comparison result like this,

```
listPerc = [listItem sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id a, id b) {
    int first = [[a objectForKey:@"perc"] intValue];
    int second = [[b objectForKey:@"perc"] intValue];

    if ( first < second ) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if ( first > second ) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    } else {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Vins I am pretty sure I missed something. Could you let me know what those errors are?

Comment: first line `incompatible block pointer types sending 'id(^)(id, id)' to parameter of type 'NSComparator' (aka 'NSComparisonResult (^)(id,id)')`

Comment: yup, I did miss something. I had to cast the result. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but why not type the block instead of casting? Hmm maybe you can't type return type.

Comment: @vakio `enums` are `int` and `NSComparisonResult` is an `NSInteger` which is a `long`.

Comment: Answer is good but use maths instead of "if / else", it's more readable :

int diff = first - second;
return diff / abs(diff);

Comment: @csblo That does not work if diff is 0. `return (0 < diff) - (diff < 0)` would be better, but the if / else is a lot more readable imho.

Answer (score 8):

A very short way of @(Deepak Danduprolu)'s answer

```c
listPerc = [listItem sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id a, id b) {
    NSNumber *first = @([[a objectForKey:@"perc"] intValue]);
    NSNumber *second = @([[b objectForKey:@"perc"] intValue]);
    return [first compare:second];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this.

```
- (void)setPlaces:(NSArray *)places
{
    if(_places != places)
    {
        _places = [places sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2){
            return [[obj1 objectForKey:FLICKR_PLACE_NAME] caseInsensitiveCompare:[obj2 objectForKey:FLICKR_PLACE_NAME]];
        }];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

I did something that was a cross between yours and the above and it works:

```
- (void)setPlaces:(NSArray *)places
{
    if(_places != places)
    {
        _places = [places sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b){
              NSString *first = [a objectForKey:FLICKR_PLACE_NAME];
              NSString *second = [b objectForKey:FLICKR_PLACE_NAME];
              return [first caseInsensitiveCompare:second];
        }
            ];
        if (self.tableView.window) [self.tableView reloadData];
    } //if _places
} //set
```