# Sort strings in dictionaries in an array by key?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, dictionary, plist, sorting

I have a plist file containing data about people (name, title, phone, email). Instead of explaining, here is a sample showing the structure:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Kontakt</key>
    <array>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>Teacher</string>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>Adam Scott</string>
                <key>phone</key>
                <string>tel://1234-567890</string>
                <key>email</key>
                <string>adam.scott@email.com</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>Teacher</string>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>Adam Scott</string>
                <key>phone</key>
                <string>tel://1234-567890</string>
                <key>email</key>
                <string>adam.scott@email.com</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>Teacher</string>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>Adam Scott</string>
                <key>phone</key>
                <string>tel://1234-567890</string>
                <key>email</key>
                <string>adam.scott@email.com</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

In code, I want to sort the strings for the key ***name***. I am then going to display the sorted array in a table view. Do anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: This would be easier to read if the text was pasted in a code block instead of using an image.

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227702/sortedarrayusingcomparator-int

Comment: @jhabbott - Edited: Pasted in the code in a code block :)